# How to I add a wildcard subdomain redirect to a subdirectory in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My old subdomain urls look something like:

```
www.newyork.website.co.uk
```

I want to redirect it now to:

```
www.website.com/city/newyork
```

However I have over 2,000 cities and just want to add a wildcard redirect. How do I go about doing this in my htaccess file?

e.g. `www.*.website.co.uk redirects to www.website.co.uk/city/*`

THis is so far over myhead but this is what I have tried to muddle together:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/city/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: rewritecond/rules on %{HTTP_HOST}, basically...

Comment: Sorry, I am am am absolute newbie. I have done some research on rewritecond rules but it is too far over my head. Is there some example code I can use?

Comment: I have added what I currently have compiled based on my research above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.(website\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.%2/city/%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It was actually just the primary domain to test if it went down before trying the subdomain

Comment: Yes. This is getting really close. It redirects the subdomain properly, but it also redirects the primary domain http://www.website.co.uk to http://www.website.co.uk/regions/www. Somehow this rule needs to ignore the primary domain.

Comment: Still redirecting the primary domain. :(.

Comment: Strike that. THere was a quick edit after I copied it. That worked. you rock!!!!!